# How to override styling in react-select npm package for different viewports using className

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, react-select

Unable to style for different viewports using `react-select` npm package.

Re: https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames

I'm trying to use `className` to override `react-select` styling, as it's compatible with `CSS modules`, and I'm defining different styling for different viewports.

However, I'm not sure how to reference the class name in the CSS file as `webpack` is obfuscating CSS class names, e.g. `PostSort_sortOption__18adQ__menu` - Any idea how to reference the class name from this?

I've tried `.sortOption__menu` but obviously that doesn't work.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @BleachedAxe unfortunately not